# Dojox Socket / Observable Store Not Updating

Tags: javascript, sockets, dojo, store, observable

I'm trying to wrap my head around repopulating a `Memory` store, which is `Observable`, using `Socket` to watch for updates.  I think i'm good with the `Memory/Observable` side, but i'm just not getting it somewhere within the `Socket` side.

The initial data is going into the store, and i'm able to observe `Socket` polling for data, and when i manually edit the data it *would* get (for testing) i can see it change in the console.

```
require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/store/Memory", "dojo/store/Observable", "dojox/socket", "dojo/domReady!"], function (dom, domConstruct, Memory, Observable, Socket) {

// initial data - would come from server
var data = [
    {"type": "foo", "unread": "2"},
    {"type": "bar", "unread": "28"},
    {"type": "baz", "unread": "19"}
];

store = new Memory({data: data});
store = Observable(store);                  

 var abc = '';

// display initial data
store.query().forEach(function(obj){
    abc += '<div class="num">' + obj.unread + '</div>';                         
});

domConstruct.place(abc, dom.byId('nums'));

// Create Socket instance
var socket = new Socket.LongPoll({ 
    url:"/path_to_my/endpoint/", // my endpoint in here returns a json object
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
});             

socket.on("message", function(event){

    var data = event.data;
    console.log(event); // i can observe updated data here

    // this is just copied from some tutorial page
    // i'm not getting how this updates the store....
    store.notify(data.action, {target: data.object, id: data.type});

});

});
```

[See this JSFiddle, for a hopefully reasonable demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/g7ouomuy/2/) The `store.notify` bit is where i'm getting unstuck...

I'm also noticing in the console that `Socket` is polling about 5 requests a second!  Is there a throttle i can apply here, or is this another sign of something amiss?